# Evento do botão voltar

Tags: android

Tenho uma aplicação que tem uma tela de Login, ela é a chamada inicial do app.
Ao logar, é chamada a ActivityMain e dela o app segue seu fluxo.

Eu gostaria de controlar o evento do botão voltar do android, gostaria que ao clicar no botão voltar não voltasse para a Activity de Login. O botão voltar do próprio android, não o do actionbar.
Coloquei o código abaixo, mas acredito não ser a melhor maneira de tratá-lo

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: No ActivityLogin, você tem que dar um finish(); para que quando o back seja apertado ele feche a main e volte ao android. Não se esqueça de apagar essas alterações no backpressed

Comment: Funcionou certinho muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Henrique,

Faltou você finalizar a Activity de login depois de abrir a MainActivity.

Agora,  se você me permite,  não é uma boa prática essa alteração do back button. O back button tem o objetivo de sempre voltar a tela anterior,  enquanto o botão de up (que fica na actionbar)  tem o objetivo de ir a tela pai da tela atual,  ou seja,  de subir a hierarquia das telas.  Dê uma lida nesse  [documento](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html).

Comment: Opa, obrigado. Colocando um finish(); na tela anterior o backbutton nao volta. Eu já retirei a implementação que está na pergunta do app, muito obrigado.